# Java EE 7 Batch API - MultiResourceItemReader counterpart

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, batch-processing, spring-batch, java-ee-7

[Spring Batch](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/) has a handy [MultiResourceItemReader](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/MultiResourceItemReader.html), I could not find a similar class in [Java EE 7 Batch Processing API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/batch-processing.htm). I'm wondering if the Java EE 7 API includes something similar. or if I can achieve the intended behavior for my flow using other Java EE services:

#### Flow:

1. A timer read "pull requests" from a central database
2. It also updates the "pull request" status to "processing"
3. For each pull request

   1. Read the origin folder for the "pull request" as well as its "destination database"
   2. For each file in the origin folder

      1. Insert a entry in the file control table of the destination database
      2. Read and insert the file contents line by line (in chunk of N lines)
      3. Update the entry written in step 2.1
      4. Move the file to a new directory
   3. Call a stored procedure in the destination database to validate and process the current "pull request" files.
4. Update the "pull request" status to "processed" in the central database.

I can write and EJB Timer for steps 1 and 2. It would fire a batch processing job for every pull request (they can run in parallel).

But I have to idea how to implement 3 (specially 3.2) without `MultiResourceItemReader`. I'm also not sure how to properly trigger step 4 after every batch job of step 3 has  finished (In an Java SE environment I would use a `CountDownLatch` for that).

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [spring.io](http://spring.io/blog/2014/05/29/spring-batch-3-0-0-is-now-ga) SB 3.0 release announce

> **JSR-352 does not provide any implementations of batch components**.
>   Spring Batch provides 17 readers, 16 writers and countless other
>   utilities and extensions that have been tested for years in enterprise
>   production environments. Spring Batch provides scalability options
>   beyond a single JVM. Finally Spring Batch provides big data support
>   both through the Spring for Apache Hadoop project and as a cornerstone
>   of Spring XD.
>
> To read more about Spring Batch's implementation of JSR-352, visit our
>   reference documentation here:
>   http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/jsr-352.html

Comment: Thanks for the info @Luca. Do you have any suggestion about how to implement the given flow without `MultiResourceItemReader`?

Comment: define a single item reader with is checkpoint is quite easy. define a multiresource can be easy too (real resource reader using a delegate). set a Resources[] properties and into checkpoint store index of current resource. be carefully to synch open/close of multiresourcereader and its delegate; the same for checkpointInfo method

Comment: sorry if the above comment is a mess,but is just an idea and I don't know JSR352 interfaces and objects. of course Resources[] must don't change during start/stop/restart of a job